# code to change imei, android id, phone number, phone name to android studio

Tags: android

I'm new to writing code, but I need to write code in Java so that it changes android id, phone number, sim card, google id, can someone help me figure out at least one of them please?

thanks in advance

I have all examples of attempts from the Internet to do this, in my opinion, there is nothing to even say